# CommunityGraphPlot without force layout

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization

I have a `Graph`, and I want to group some of its vertices into communities. `CommunityGraphPlot` uses force directed layout and its doesn't look like the original graph after I apply `CommunityGraphPlot`. I don't want the vertices of same community to come close so that the community border line can be drawn easily. I want the vertices to stay in their position as it was in the graph. Just drawing even some rectangles or any other shape over them will be fine for me.

```
CompleteGraph[8, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image: Beautiful]

```
CommunityGraphPlot[
 CompleteGraph[8, 
  VertexLabels -> "Name"], {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {4, 8}}]
```

[image: Just breaks the beauty]

Given that complete graph above, `CommunityGraphPlot` just breaks its beauty, It doesn't even look like once its was a complete graph. However with these set of vertices it could have draw regions easily while keeping the vertices in their position.

Comment: It doesn't even look like a kite or fish. I don't know what this beast is. But if it was not a community plot. I wouldn't believe so easily that it was actually a Complete Graph.

Comment: What if communities are 'evenly' distributed and making their outlines leads to an unreadable graph?

Comment: In that case we would say that it is unreadable in this way. We cant retain the original look and feel, So let us try a force layout. Reasonable compromise.

Comment: If you all you want is to drawn regions, then I suggest doing that manually and not using CommunityGraphPlot at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to draw blob like CommunityGraphPlot:

```
iBlobs[style_, pts_, size_] :=
 Block[{epts},
  epts = Flatten[Tuples[CoordinateBounds[#, size]] & /@ pts, 1];
  {style, 
   FilledCurve@
    BSplineCurve[MeshPrimitives[ConvexHullMesh[epts], 1][[All, 1, 1]],
      SplineClosed -> True]}
  ]

{cliques, style} = {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {4, 8}}, {Red, Green, Blue}};
vcoord = GraphEmbedding[g];

bsize = .08 Differences[MinMax[vcoord]][[1]];

bstyle = Directive[Opacity[.3], EdgeForm[#], #] & /@ style;

cpoints = vcoord[[VertexIndex[g, #] & /@ #]] & /@ cliques;

HighlightGraph[g, cliques, 
 Epilog -> 
  Activate[Thread[Inactive[iBlobs][bstyle, cpoints, bsize]]], 
 ImagePadding -> 20]
```

[image]

Comment: Does it require the graph to be a complete graph ?

Comment: I am getting errors like `Part::partd: Part specification MeshPrimitives[ConvexHullMesh[{{{-0.16,-1.16},{0.16,-1.16}},{{0.16,-1.16},{0.16,-0.84}},{{0.16,-0.84},{0.16,1.16}},{{0.16,1.16},{-0.16,1.16}},{{-0.16,1.16},{-0.16,0.84}},{{-0.16,0.84},{-0.16,-1.16}}}],1][[All,1,1]] is longer than depth of object.`

Comment: ups.. there is a typo. I fixed it.

Comment: Yes it is working with Complete Graphs now. I hope this does not require the graph to be Complete. My actual graph is not a complete graph. So is it supposed to work there ?

Comment: Thanks it worked with my actual graph too. I made some minor tweaks with `bsize` (changed 0.08 to 0.01).

Comment: Along with the Communities you are also coloring the vertices. I don't want that how do I turn that off ?

Comment: Then don't use HighlightGraph.  Just do Graph[g, Epilog->.., ImagePadding->20]

Comment: Okay Thanks It Worked

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** Using `` GraphComputation`GraphCommunitiesPlotDump`generateBlobs ``, ... well, to generate blobs:

```
ClearAll[blobF, fC]
fC[coords_, size_: .04] := Module[{}, CommunityGraphPlot[Graph[{}], {}]; 
  FilledCurve @ BSplineCurve[GraphComputation`GraphCommunitiesPlotDump`generateBlobs[# &, 
    {coords}, size][[2, 1]], SplineClosed -> True]]


blobF[g_, cols_, coms_, size_: .04] := Thread[{cols, EdgeForm[{Gray, Thin}], Opacity[.25],
    fC[PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexCoordinates] & /@ #, size] & /@ coms}];

{cliques,  colors} = {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}}, {Red, Green , Blue}};
cg = CompleteGraph[8];
SetProperty[cg, {Epilog -> blobF[cg, colors, cliques], 
  VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 15}]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1]
Row[{#, SetProperty[#, {Epilog -> blobF[#, colors, cliques], ImagePadding -> 15}]} &@
  RandomGraph[{20, 15}, ImageSize -> 300, VertexLabels -> "Name"]]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
{cliques,  colors} = {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}}, {Red, Green , Blue}};
lines = Thread[{colors, CapForm["Round"], JoinForm["Round"], 
  Opacity[.5], AbsoluteThickness[20], 
  Line[PropertyValue[{cg, #}, VertexCoordinates] & /@ #] & /@ cliques}];

SetProperty[CompleteGraph[8], {Epilog -> lines, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
  ImagePadding -> 15}]
```

[image]

Or highlight `Subgraph`s:

```
cg = CompleteGraph[8];
Fold[HighlightGraph[##] &, cg, (Style[Subgraph[cg, #[[1]]], #[[2]], 
   CapForm["Round"], JoinForm["Round"], AbsoluteThickness[20]] & /@ 
 Transpose[{cliques, colors}])]
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried your updated code but it looks different, the hulls don't fit in the vertices https://i.imgur.com/Wrs8Wzb.png

Comment: @NeelBasu,  it turns out we need to invoke `CommunityGraphPlot`  before using ``GraphComputation`GraphCommunitiesPlotDump`generateBlobs`` for it to load. So using `CommunityGraphPlot[Graph[{}], {}]`  before it works. I modified the definition of `fC` to get this line in.