# Marking communities in a weighted adjacency graph based on a threshold

Tags: graphs-and-networks

There are a few questions that are *close* to what I seek, most notably [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211140/customize-community-graph), but none quite right.

I want to exploit *Mathematica*'s CommunityGraph style in which a boundary is drawn around a "community" in an undirected graph.  However, I want to define automatically or by hand a threshold distance (edge weight) for community membership.  Here's a minimal example:

```
testMat = {
   {\[Infinity], 1, 1, 10, 11},
   {1, \[Infinity], 1, 11, 10},
   {1, 1, \[Infinity], 9, 10},
   {10, 11, 9, \[Infinity], 1},
   {11, 10, 10, 1, \[Infinity]}};

WeightedAdjacencyGraph[testMat,
 GraphLayout -> {"SpringElectricalEmbedding", "EdgeWeighted" -> True}]
```

[image: Graph]

Clearly there are two "communities" or clusters here.  (Technically, in graph theory there is just one community... I'm defining a community based on distances.)

I can find the clusters by ClusterComponents based on the VertexCoordinates, but I don't know how to use the internal drawing procedures to encircle and highlight the clusters.  In my large actual graph, the layout shape of each cluster is not circular, indeed it may not be convex.

I'd also like to retain the straight edges, which indicate edge weight or distance.  CommunityGraphPlot isn't quite right because it breaks the edge structure (which I must retain), as you can see here:

[image: Community Plot]

The ideal functionality would be an option for HighlightGraph, which encircles a subgraph, but *Mathematica* does not support that functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an input graph `g`, we can use `NearestNeighborGraph` with `GraphEmbedding[g]` as the vertex list and `{All, thresholddistance}` as the second argument and find the `ConnectedComponents` to get vertex clusters.

To generate *convex* blobs enclosing vertex clusters can use the function `fC` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163473/125) and use the blobs as `Prolog` in `Graph`.

```
ClearAll[fC, nnG, addCommunityBlobs]

fC[coords_, size_: .015] := Module[{}, CommunityGraphPlot[Graph[{}], {}];
  FilledCurve @ BSplineCurve[ 
    GraphComputation`GraphCommunitiesPlotDump`generateBlobs[# &, 
      {coords}, size][[2, 1]], SplineClosed -> True]]

nnG[g_, t_] := NearestNeighborGraph[GraphEmbedding @ g, {All, t}]
  

addCommunityBlobs[g_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Graph[g, opts, 
  VertexLabels -> "Index", ImagePadding -> 15, 
  Prolog -> MapIndexed[{Opacity[.3, ColorData[97]@#2[[1]]], fC @ #} &, 
    ConnectedComponents @ g]]
```

***Example:***

```
wag = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[testMat, 
   GraphLayout -> {"SpringElectricalEmbedding", "EdgeWeighted" -> True}];

Manipulate[addCommunityBlobs[graph[t], ImageSize -> Large],
 {{t, .126}, .12, .13, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 Initialization :> {graph[t_] := nnG[wag, t]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh perfect.  Absolutely perfect.  Thanks so very much!  ($\checkmark$)